# Does LocalBroadcastManager deliver events in the order in which the events wer sent?

Tags: android, localbroadcastmanager

I have an activity A and a service S. They commute via LocalBroadcastManager.

If S calls sendBroadcast twice with two messages M1 and M2 in order, will A get M1 before M2?

Thanks,

Comment: BTW, if you want this sort of local messaging, but with more options, check out [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and [Square's Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).

Comment: Which one has a better support and is used by more projects?

Comment: They're close, though I suspect that Otto is used a bit more. Support for both is mostly just issue trackers and public resources like StackOverflow, AFAIK.

Comment: I went through http://square.github.io/otto/. It said 'Posting to the bus is a synchronous action so when program execution continues it is guaranteed that all subscribers have been called.' I am curious why it does not provide async posting. Will performance be an issue here if we only have sync posting?

Comment: And https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus does not mention whether its post is async or sync.

Comment: Actually, it does, but it discusses it in the context of delivery threads: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus#delivery-threads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LocalBroadcastManager` has two ways for you to broadcast; `sendBroadcast()` and `sendBroadcastSync()`. One is synchronous, and the other is asynchronous. `sendBroadcastSync()` blocks until the receiver for the first message is done running.

Comment: IOW, with `sendBroadcastSync()`, you can be guaranteed order, because M1 will be delivered before you have a chance to send M2. With `sendBroadcast()`, I think the net effect will be that they are delivered in order, but that's not documented behavior and therefore is probably something you should not rely upon.

Comment: How about the delay of sendBroadcastSync()? Intuitively, in my case it does not seem to be a very busy operation because I only use it to commute two components. Am I correct?

Comment: It will depend on how much your receiver takes to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. This call deliver method is asynchronous, there is another way of sending **ordered** broadcasts (based on permissions, basically the one's that have more permissions get the broadcast earlier than the rest), `sendOrderedBroadcast(...)`. You may find more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: There is no `sendOrderedBroadcast()` on `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Comment: True, the solution I posted is from `Context`, not `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Comment: the OP is probably only wanting to broadcast locally and avoid IPC overhead.