# Android IntentService/Service to request/send data to web service and getting the progress to UI

Tags: android, file-upload, broadcastreceiver, intentservice, localbroadcastmanager

On Android basically, I am trying to upload/download data from a web service and have a progress bar that should be rendered showing the progress percentage.

Following is the approach that I implemented along with the reason for considering them:

1. **Chose `IntentService` to run in background:**
   As per the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Lifecycle) I could not use bound service as it will destroy when the binded Activity/Fragment is destroyed. Hence the selection of `IntentService` over `Service`. Move over it would be one time and intent service works on a worker thread so it is much better.
2. **Broadcast to receive updates:**
   Implementation of `LocalBroadcastManager` to update the progress bar UI by registering it to listen to the broadcast received from the `IntentService` described above.

However with this approach, the following issue needs to be addressed:

Sequence of broadcasts is not maintained. The broadcast carries the percentage of progress of the upload/download. But since the sequence is not maintained, there are chances that I receive stale updates (eg: I may receive 30% after 40%). I also tried using `sendBroadcastSync` method of the `LocalBroadcastManager` but it doesn't work consistently *(I am not very sure on this)*. Hence I tried to implement `Messenger` via `Handler` however I got to know that the approach will not be able to reconnect to the on going upload/download once the UI is re-created (Activitiy/Fragment is destroyed and created). Basically the reference to the `Handler` is lost along with the previous activity/fragment and hence the messages are not delivered to the UI for update.

I have been trying to get my way about since a while but I am not able to get it done. Your words of wisdom will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about the problem a bit differently, as ordering of messages may be a problem with a variety of message solutions.

The fact that you get the 40% event after the 30% event is not really a problem. What *is* a problem is if you update the UI to reflect 30%.

Have each event (each `Intent` when using `LocalBroadcastManager` as your event bus) contain a timestamp along with the percentage-complete. Track in your UI the last-seen event timestamp. If you get an event that is older than your last-seen event timestamp, ignore that event.

If you are sure that your percentage is monotonically increasing — in other words, that there is no legitimate scenario in which you might drop from 40% to 30% complete — you could skip the timestamp and just only apply new percentages that are higher than your currently-showing percentage.

Answer (score 2):

How about using an interface. UI: get instance and setCallback() when activity/fragment created, Service: get instance and call update(use a handler if not called from the main thread, handler.post(runnable {... update ...})).

If you want to notify multiple UI instances, keep an ArrayList in the updater class, and modify the 'setCallback' method to 'addCallback', and update every list item in 'update'.

```
public class ProgressUpdater {
    private static ProgressUpdater sUpdater;
    private UpdateCallback mCallback;

    public interface UpdateCallback {
        public void update(long progress);
    }

    public void setCallback(UpdateCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public void update(long progress) {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.update(progress);
        }
    }

    public static ProgressUpdater getInstance() {
        if (null == sUpdater) {
            sUpdater = new ProgressUpdater();
        }
        return sUpdater;
    }

    private ProgressUpdater() {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a Singleton pattern and it should update without either the `Messenger` or `Broadcast`. I will need to check this out. However there is a point of concern. Once the UI (Activity/Fragment) is destroyed, the `mCallback` will be going to `null`. Isn't there a chance that there will be a null pointer exception in that case?

Comment: I set a callback in the activity that shows a toast, and call update in the service every 5 seconds. the result is, even if the activity had been destoryed, the toast still shows up. Use a weakreference for the callback if you are worried about leaking the activity context. @Tejas

Answer (score 1):

If you want to constantly update your ui then we can start a local broadcast manager from a service and register your broadcast receiver in your activity.

Comment: The issue with the broadcast manager is that the order is not guaranteed by the system. Kindly find the explanation here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/28513424/1161911